# java binary does not come with openjdk-6-jdk?

Tags: java

I must be going mad, and missing something obvious, but I can't make any sense of this at all, so any help would be hugely appreciated.

I am installing java 6 on a new Ubuntu 12.10 machine.  I do:

```
sudo aptitude install openjdk-6-jdk
```

which supposedly installs everything.  But for some reason it comes with virtually none of the jre:

```
richard@holly:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin$ ls -atl
total 48
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Dec 12 11:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root  4096 Dec 12 11:54 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39600 Oct 24 18:54 policytool
```

I've tried installing openjdk-6-jre, but it says that it is already installed.

Totally totally baffled.  What am I missing?

Cheers,

Richard

Comment: Just thinking: have you tried to download the oracle java 6 jdk and install that?

Comment: try the following command:
which javac

Comment: Have a look in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin`

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, folks.  javac is in: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac, but the java binary isn't in the same directory.  It may well come to downloading and installing the package from the oracle site, yes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dpkg-query to find out what files are included in a package:

`dpkg-query -L openjdk-6-jdk`

... which will show the location of the java executable as /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-$ARCH/bin ($ARCH being your architecture).

Comment: Thanks, that's a generally useful command that I didn't know.  Unfortunately, this just tells me that the java binary isn't in the packages openjdk-6-jdk or openjdk-6-jre :)  Might have to resort to downloading the binaries from the oracle site ...

Comment: Hmm, you're right. I ran `dpkg-query -S /usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-6-i386/bin/java` and it reported that the owning package was 'openjdk-6-jre-headless'. This is on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2):

When you installed openjdk-6-jre, it should have also included its dependency openjdk-6-jre-headless, which is the package that includes the java binary.

The contents of the /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin directory are directly populated by the packages. If there are files missing then there is something gravely wrong with the system.

You should confirm that both packages are installed using the `dpkg -l` command:

```
dpkg -l openjdk-6-jre openjdk-6-jre-headless
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                     Version                  Description
+++-========================-========================-================================================================
ii  openjdk-6-jre            6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12. OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
ii  openjdk-6-jre-headless   6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12. OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
```

If for some reason openjdk-6-jre-headless is not installed, then install it.

There should be links for java and other executables in /usr/bin created by the openjdk-6-jre and openjdk-6-jre-headless postinst (post installation) script. If you want to examine the postinst scripts, they and other package scripts found in /var/lib/dpkg/info as .postinst.

As a handy tip, a command similar to this will list a chain of symbolic links to a non-link terminator.

```
f=/usr/bin/java; while [ -h $f ]; do ls -l $f; f=$(readlink $f); done; ls -l $f
```